# Reactjs setState not updating for this one function only

Tags: reactjs

For this application, clicking a listed item once should create a button component underneath this listed item. Clicking the button should cause this listed item to be deleted.

I am currently facing difficulty trying to 'delete' the listed item after the button is clicked. Here is the code that went wrong (this is found in CountdownApp component) :

```
handleDelete(index) {
    console.log('in handleDelete')
    console.log(index)
    let countdownList = this.state.countdowns.slice()
    countdownList.splice(index, 1)
    console.log(countdownList) // countdownList array is correct

    this.setState({
        countdowns: countdownList
    }, function() {
        console.log('after setState')
        console.log(this.state.countdowns) // this.state.countdowns does not match countdownList
        console.log(countdownList) // countdownList array is still correct
    })
}
```

In the code above, I removed the item to be deleted from countdownList array with splice and tried to re-render the app with setState. However, the new state countdowns do not reflect this change. In fact, it returns the unedited state.

I have also tried the following:

```
handleDelete(index) {
    this.setState({
        countdowns: [] // just using an empty array to check if setState still works
    }, function() {
        console.log('after setState')
        console.log(this.state.countdowns)
    })
}
```

In the code above, I tried setting state to be an empty array. The console log for this.state.countdowns did not print out an empty array. It printed out the unedited state again

This is the only event handler that isn't working and I have no idea why (main question of this post) :/

If I have 'setstate' wrongly, why does the other 'setState' in other parts of my code work?? (I would like to request an in-depth explanation)

This is all my code for this app (its a small app) below:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class DeleteButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <button onClick={this.props.onDelete}>
                    delete
                </button>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

class Countdown extends React.Component {
    render () {
        //console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <li 
                onClick={this.props.onClick}
                onDoubleClick={this.props.onDoubleClick}
            >
                {this.props.title} - {this.props.days}, {this.props.color}
                {this.props.showDeleteButton ? <DeleteButton onDelete={this.props.onDelete}/> : null }
            </li>
        )
    }
}

const calculateOffset = date => {
    let countdown = new Date(date)
    let today = new Date
    let timeDiff = countdown.getTime() - today.getTime()
    let diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24))
    return diffDays
}

class CountdownList extends React.Component {
    countdowns() {
        let props = this.props
        // let onClick = this.props.onClick
        // let onDoubleClick = this.props.onDoubleClick
        let rows = []
        this.props.countdowns.forEach(function(countdown, index) {
             rows.push(
                <Countdown 
                    key={index}
                    title={countdown.title} 
                    days={calculateOffset(countdown.date)}
                    color={countdown.color}
                    showDeleteButton={countdown.showDeleteButton}
                    onDelete={() => props.onDelete(index)}
                    onClick={() => props.onClick(index)}
                    onDoubleClick={() => props.onDoubleClick(index)}
                />
            )           
        })
        return rows
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.countdowns()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class InputField extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input 
                type='text'
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                value={this.props.input}
                onChange={this.props.handleInput}
            />
        )
    }
}

class DatePicker extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input 
                type='date'
                value={this.props.date}
                onChange={this.props.handleDateInput}
            />
        )
    }
}

class CountdownForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            title: this.props.title || '',
            date: this.props.date || '',
            color: this.props.color || ''
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            title: nextProps.title || '',
            date: nextProps.date || '',
            color: nextProps.color || ''
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.props.onSubmit(this.state, this.reset())
    }

    reset() {
        this.setState({
            title: '',
            date: '',
            color: ''
        })
    }

    handleTitleInput(e) {
        this.setState({
            title: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleDateInput(e) {
        this.setState({
            date: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleColorInput(e) {
        this.setState({
            color: e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form
                onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}
            >
                <h3>Countdown </h3>
                <InputField 
                    placeholder='title'
                    input={this.state.title}
                    handleInput={(e) => this.handleTitleInput(e)}
                />
                <DatePicker 
                    date={this.state.date}
                    handleDateInput={(e) => this.handleDateInput(e)}
                />
                <InputField 
                    placeholder='color'
                    input={this.state.color}
                    handleInput={(e) => this.handleColorInput(e)}
                />
                <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

class CountdownApp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            countdowns: [
                {title: 'My Birthday', date: '2017-07-25', color: '#cddc39', showDeleteButton: false},
                {title: 'Driving Practice', date: '2017-07-29', color: '#8bc34a', showDeleteButton: false},
                {title: 'Korean BBQ', date: '2017-08-15', color: '#8bc34a', showDeleteButton: false}
            ]
        }
    }

    handleCountdownForm(data) {
        if (this.state.editId) {
            const index = this.state.editId
            let countdowns = this.state.countdowns.slice()
            countdowns[index] = data
            this.setState({
                title: '',
                date: '',
                color: '',
                editId: null,
                countdowns
            })

        } else {
            data.showDeleteButton = false
            const history = this.state.countdowns.slice()
            this.setState({
                countdowns: history.concat(data),
            })
        }
    }

    handleDelete(index) {
        console.log('in handleDelete')
        console.log(index)
        let countdownList = this.state.countdowns.slice()
        countdownList.splice(index, 1)
        console.log(countdownList)

        this.setState({
            countdowns: countdownList
        }, function() {
            console.log('after setState')
            console.log(this.state.countdowns)
        })
    }

    handleCountdown(index) {
        const countdownList = this.state.countdowns.slice()
        let countdown = countdownList[index]
        countdown.showDeleteButton = !countdown.showDeleteButton
        this.setState({
            countdowns: countdownList
        })
    }

    handleDblClick(index) {
        const countdownList = this.state.countdowns
        const countdown = countdownList[index]
        this.setState({
            title: countdown.title,
            date: countdown.date,
            color: countdown.color,
            editId: index
        })
    }
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <CountdownForm 
                title={this.state.title}
                date={this.state.date}
                color={this.state.color}
                onSubmit={(data) => {this.handleCountdownForm(data)}}
            />
            <CountdownList 
                countdowns={this.state.countdowns}
                onDelete={(index) => this.handleDelete(index)}
                onClick={(index) => this.handleCountdown(index)}
                onDoubleClick={(index) => this.handleDblClick(index)}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <CountdownApp />,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer to my own question!

setState worked as expected. The bug was due to `<li>` container that wrapped the event handler.

Clicking `<li>` causes it to call onClick event (which is managed by handleCountdown function in CountdownApp component) which causes it to setState.

As the delete button was wrapped in `<li>` container, clicking the delete button calls 2 event listeners - handleCountdown and handleDelete. handleCountdown is called twice in this case, once from clicking `<li>` to expand and the next call when the delete button is clicked.

There is a high chance that the last async setState dispatched from handleCountdown overwrites handleDelete's setState. Hence, the bug.

Here is changes: (I recoded everything again so the names might differ a little but the logic stays the same)

```
    class Countdown extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <li>
                <div onClick={this.props.onClick} > // Add this div wrapper!
                    {this.props.title} - {this.props.days}, {this.props.color}
                </div>
                {this.props.toShow ? 
                <ButtonsGroup 
                    onDelete={this.props.onDelete} 
                    onEdit={this.props.onEdit}
                /> 
                : null}
            </li>
        )
    }
}
```

So the solution is to separate the clickable area and the buttons. I added a div wrapper over the text in `<li>` so whenever the text in `<li>` is clicked, the added `<ul>` will be out of onClick event handler area.